# Whats the point of DOCTYPE?

Tags: html, doctype

I know that different doctypes are essentially about how compliant the html is, but what difference does it make what doctype you specify? Do browsers handle the same code differently depending on the doctype?
Thanks

UPDATE - most answers mention quirks mode can be set off if no doctype is specified. But what would be the different between xhtml and html 4.01?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The biggest thing is having a doctype or not. If you don't, the browser will work in a "quirks" mode rather than standards mode and many things will be slightly different. If you have one — any — that typically activates more standards-compliant behavior in the browser.

See [this article](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) for the details of what doctypes do on various different browsers and what modes — quirks, standards, almost-standards, etc. — different browsers have. Quoting a relevant section:

> **Modes for text/html Content**
>
> The choice
>   of the mode for text/html content
>   depends on doctype sniffing (discussed
>   later in this document). In IE8 and
>   IE9, the mode also depends on other
>   factors. However, by default even in
>   IE8 and IE9, the mode depends on the
>   doctype for non-intranet sites that
>   are not on a blacklist supplied by
>   Microsoft.
>
> **It cannot be stressed
>   enough that the exact behavior of the
>   modes varies from browser to browser
>   even though discussion in this
>   document has been unified.**
>
> **Quirks Mode**
>
> In the Quirks mode the
>   browsers violate contemporary Web
>   format specifications in order to
>   avoid “breaking” pages authored
>   according to practices that were
>   prevalent in the late 1990s. Different
>   browsers implement different quirks.
>   In Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8 and 9,
>   the Quirks mode is effectively frozen
>   IE 5.5. In other browsers, the Quirks
>   mode is a handful of deviations from
>   the Almost Standards mode.
>
> If you are authoring new pages now,
>   you are supposed to comply with the
>   relevant specifications (CSS 2.1 in
>   particular) and use the Standards
>   mode.
>
> **Standards Mode**
>
> In the Standards mode
>   the browsers try to give conforming
>   documents the specification-wise
>   correct treatment to the extent
>   implemented in a particular browser.
>
> Since different browsers are at
>   different stages of compliance, the
>   Standards mode isn’t a single target,
>   either.
>
> HTML 5 calls this mode the “no quirks
>   mode”.
>
> **Almost Standards Mode**
>
> Firefox, Safari,
>   Chrome, Opera (since 7.5), IE8 and IE9
>   also have a mode known as “the Almost
>   Standards mode”, which implements the
>   vertical sizing of table cells
>   traditionally and not rigorously
>   according to the CSS2 specification.
>   Mac IE 5, Windows IE 6 and 7, Opera
>   prior to 7.5 and Konqueror do not need
>   an Almost Standards mode, because they
>   don’t implement the vertical sizing of
>   table cells rigorously according to
>   the CSS2 specification in their
>   respective Standards modes anyway. In
>   fact, their Standards modes are closer
>   to the Almost Standards mode than to
>   the Standards mode of newer browsers.
>
> HTML 5 calls this mode the “limited
>   quirks mode”.
>
> **IE7 Mode**
>
> IE8 and IE9 have a mode that
>   is mostly a frozen copy of the mode
>   that was the Standards mode in IE7.
>   Other browsers do not have a mode like
>   this, and this mode is not specified
>   by HTML5.
>
> **IE8 Standards Mode**
>
> IE9 has a mode that
>   is mostly a frozen copy of the mode
>   that was the Standards mode in IE8.
>   Other browsers do not have a mode like
>   this, and this mode is not specified
>   by HTML5.
>
> **IE8 Almost Standards Mode**
>
> IE9 has a
>   mode that is mostly a frozen copy of
>   the mode that was the Almost Standards
>   mode in IE8. Other browsers do not
>   have a mode like this, and this mode
>   is not specified by HTML5.

...but see the article for a full discussion.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration):

> A Document Type Declaration, or
>   DOCTYPE, **is an instruction that
>   associates a particular SGML or XML
>   document (for example, a webpage) with
>   a Document Type Definition (DTD) (for
>   example, the formal definition of a
>   particular version of HTML)**. In the
>   serialized form of the document, it
>   manifests as a short string of markup
>   that conforms to a particular syntax.
>
> The HTML layout engines in modern web
>   browsers perform DOCTYPE "sniffing" or
>   "switching", **wherein the DOCTYPE in a
>   document served as text/html
>   determines a layout mode, such as
>   "quirks mode" or "standards mode"**. The
>   text/html serialization of **HTML5,
>   which is not SGML-based, uses the
>   DOCTYPE only for mode selection**. Since
>   web browsers are implemented with
>   special-purpose HTML parsers, rather
>   than general-purpose DTD-based
>   parsers, they don't use DTDs and will
>   never access them even if a URL is
>   provided. **The DOCTYPE is retained in
>   HTML5 as a "mostly useless, but
>   required" header only to trigger
>   "standards mode" in common browsers**.

I decided to quote this text because it answers your question better than I would :). It is important that the absence of a DOCTYPE will trigger "quirks mode" in certain browsers.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the standards and yes, browsers handles code differently. That means, that all browsers *should* display the page equally. If no standard is specified, browser will interpret the page as it wants.

Answer (score 2):

The  declaration is not an XHTML tag; it is an instruction to the web browser about what version of the markup language the page is written in.

The  declaration refers to a Document Type Definition (DTD). The DTD specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the content correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The DOCTYPE declaration is required to be compliant to SGML, the language HTML is an instance of.

The DOCTYPE declaration is used by some browsers to [trigger different rendering modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes).

Answer (score 2):

> **Browser Modes**

Back in the past, Browsers implemented CSS to their own rules.
Only over the years have Browser now adapted the W3C standards.

To make sure that websites rendered correctly various browsers, web developers had to implement CSS according to the wishes of these browsers. Thus, most websites used CSS in ways that didn’t quite match the specifications.

Therefore, when standards compliancy became important browser vendors faced a tough choice. Moving closer to the W3C specifications was the way to go, but if they’d just change the CSS implementations to match the standards perfectly, many websites would break to a greater or lesser extent. Existing CSS would start to show odd side effects if it were suddenly interpreted in the correct way.

So moving closer to standards compliance would cause problems. On the other hand, not moving closer to standards compliance would perpetuate the general confusion of the Browser Wars Era.

To this end all Browser had to start supporting both modes. Quirks mode for older designs and standard mode for new design.

Paraphrased from here: [Quirks mode and strict mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html)

> **DocTypes**

*Choosing which mode to use requires a trigger, and this trigger was found in ’doctype switching’.
  According to the standards, any (X)HTML document should have a doctype which tells the world at large which flavour of (X)HTML the document is using.*

Taken from here too: [Quirks mode and strict mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html)

> **Additonal Resources**

- [Document Type Declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocType)
- [Quirks Mode on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)
- [Quirks mode and strict mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html)
- [Internet Explorer box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)
- [The CSS box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Answer (score 1):

The doctype declaration should be the first thing in an HTML document, before the  tag.

It isn't an HTML tag; **it's an instruction to the web browser about what version of the markup language the page is written in.**

It's getting simpler with HTML5: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

If you don't have that proper doctype, the browser won't know to use HTML5.

Answer (score -1):

Because Doctype is the flag to tell how the browser should handle the page.

For example :

HTML5 need this doctype`<!DOCTYPE html>`
If you remove this from the page, the any HTML5 capabilities inside your page won't be activated.

You can read more in http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype

Comment: Definitely not. Browsers don't differentiate versions of HTML. Your browser will be able to use HTML5 features inside your page whether you use HTML5 doctype, XHTML1 doctype or HTML4 doctype (just make sure your doctype triggers standards-compliance mode).

Comment: sorry Rudy I had to downvote you because it's incorrect to say that html5 won't work without a doctype. The browser just _might_ not run in standards compliant mode if you leave it out

Comment: From docs: _The DOCTYPE declaration is <!DOCTYPE html> and is case-insensitive in the HTML syntax. DOCTYPEs from earlier versions of HTML were longer because the HTML language was SGML-based and therefore required a reference to a DTD. With HTML5 this is no longer the case and *the DOCTYPE is only needed to enable standards mode for documents written using the HTML syntax*. Browsers already do this for <!DOCTYPE html>._

Comment: @Stephenmurdoch : are you sure? From W3C page(http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html) :"DOCTYPEs are required for legacy reasons. When omitted, browsers tend to use a different rendering mode that is incompatible with some specifications. Including the DOCTYPE in a document ensures that the browser makes a best-effort attempt at following the relevant specifications." The last time I forgot to put one, my HTML5 related code was not working at all.

Comment: If you don't use doctype, it will trigger quirks mode and this will cause incorrect rendering and inability to use HTML5 features in some browsers. However, the standards-compliant mode triggered by HTML5 doctype is the same as standards-compliant mode triggered by other doctypes. If I use `<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">`, I will be able to use canvas, HTML5 video and all other HTML5 features and it will work everywhere.