# Trouble using separate css files

Tags: html, css, file

So I originally created my webpage all in one php file, and all the css styling worked as intended. However, now that I've gone ahead to try to split up the code by putting all the css in its own file, my php page is does not include any of the styling from the css page. I'm sure i've made a simple error, but I can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong. The the link to my folder is Computer --> MWebsite --> Login --> login_template.php and css folder ( --> design.css ).

Here's the top of the php page...

**login_template.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CarPals</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
</head>
<body>
```

and here's the top of the css page just to show how I have it laid out...

**design.css**

```
h1 {text-align: center; color: #bdd0d9 }
a {color: #f75d59; text-decoration: underline; }
yy2 {color: #808080; font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif; font-size:12px;}
yy3 {color: #6D9BC6; font-size: 30px; font-family: "palatino linotype", Book Antiqua, Palatino, serif;  font-weight:bold;}
body {width:100%; background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 497, color-stop(0, #4D4D4D))}
.dotted {margin:-7px; border: 1px dotted #808080; border-style: none none solid; color: #000; background-color: #F2F2F2; }   
#outline {background:#696969; position: absolute; top: 0px; margin: -10px; width:1287; height:80px;}
#outline-text {position:absolute; top:-12px; left:200px; width:300px;}  
#break {height:15px} 
#break2 {height:10px} 
#break3 {height:15px} 
#frm {
        background: #6e6e6e;
        margin:auto;
        top:320px; left:857px; width:243px; height:230px;
        position:absolute;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif; font-size: 7px; font-style: italic;
        line-height: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #C0C0C0;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding:10px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        border: inset 1px solid #333;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    }
```

Comment: this may be just a simple issue of an omitted "/" in the path to the style sheet.

Comment: the <link> tag should have to have a closing tag, like <link></link>, if not just add / in the end like <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/design.css" />

Comment: @user2277872 only if it's XHTML, not HTML.

Comment: I've tried it with and without the "/" but it doesn't affect the outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that you are just missing the [`type`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_type.asp) attribute for the link tag. Try with `type="text/css"` and see how that goes.

Also, you may want to add the `media` attribute as well which will help define what type of media this CSS document is for. [Here is some information regarding the media attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp)

**EDIT**

Here how Stack Overflow's CSS is included (exact HTML at time of edit):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=0f0c93534e2b">
```

**EDIT**

Further checks that would be worthwhile include doing [CSS Validation](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) and if fixing any issues with that doesn't solve your problem, it may be actually accessing the CSS file.

Check that the page you visit in the browser is relative to your CSS document. If the page you are physically accessing in the URL (ie. http://youwebsitehere.com/youPage.php) is not relative to the CSS (as your CSS href is relative - "css/design.css") so you would want to be able to access your CSS via http://youwebsitehere.com/css/design.css

Comment: The type attribute isn't mandatory, it's optional. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372260/correct-syntax-for-include-css-file

Comment: `type` is not required as of html5 (http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/document-metadata.html#the-link-element)

Comment: Type might not be required for HTML5 however he doesn't have the HTML5 doctype for the document. Thanks for pointing it out though for HTML5, I myself did not know that.

Comment: he doesn't have a `DOCTYPE` whatsoever; html5 is implemented by default

Comment: Pretty sure HTML5 is not implemented by default. Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213242/whats-the-point-of-doctype), it seems that it uses an almost quirks mode.

Comment: I tried adding the "type" line, but it doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: Try doing a [CSS Validation](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) on your CSS to see if there is something we missed in there stopping it from working.

Comment: Or if it isn't the CSS markup that is the issue, it may be that the PHP page physically can't access the file. While you stated the folder structure in your question, double check that relative to the URL of the page that the CSS file can be accessed. (ie. http://yourWebsiteHere.com/yourPage.php and http://yourWebsiteHere.com/css/design.css)

Comment: I tried the CSS validation page, and while I did find a couple of other small error, none of them were causing the lack os styling to appear.

Comment: @Turnerj that might be the problem. THe php page loads fine, but when I type in the css page in the url ("Mywebsite.com/css/design.css") I get a "Page not found" error

Comment: In that case, you might be able to just use `design.css` instead of `css/design.css` in your `link` tag. I don't know how your site is configured but it is a little strange that your CSS folder is the root of the site (based on the URL).

Comment: My goodness. Okay so what finally worked was just having href="design.css" not "css/design.css". I managed to try all different variations of ../../design.css but never just design.css haha. I thought I had to have the name of the folder it was in, but I guess not. Thank you to everyone who commented. I'll update the code to show the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

In the style for the body tag you're missing a closing parentheses at the end of the line, that might make the rest of the code invalid.
right after `color-stop`, the inner nested parentheses.

Comment: Good pick up with that. As the declaration is on the one line, that definitely might affect all the other styles in the document, making it look like it is not working.

Comment: Can you elaborate on where I'm missing the parentheses... I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Oh I see what you're talking about. That was definitely an error on my end, but after fixing it, it still did not affect the main problem.

Comment: One the line where the body styles are declared in the CSS, at the very end on the right

Comment: yah I fixed that, but I'm still having the same problem